# What does "< >" mean in my database query output?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I wrote a query to extract data from neo4j database which is connected to my Django app using neomodel module. The output is in this format:

```
[[<Node id=32 labels={'Resource', 'owl__Class'} properties={'ns1__images': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Tottori_sand_dune02_1920.jpg/120px-Tottori_sand_dune02_1920.jpg','ns1__definition': 'Camels\xa0are\xa0a\xa0milk-producing animal.'}>]]
```

I've tried using loops and accessing specific element using the index but they didn't help.

This is the query I ran:

```
results, meta = db.cypher_query("MATCH (n) WHERE n.uri =  RETURN n")
```

What I tried and didn't help:

```
print(results[0][0])
```

This gives output as:

```
<Node id=32 labels={'Resource', 'owl__Class'} properties={'ns1__images': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Tottori_sand_dune02_1920.jpg/120px-Tottori_sand_dune02_1920.jpg','ns1__definition': 'Camels\xa0are\xa0a\xa0milk-producing animal.'}>
```

And when I use this:

```
print(list(results[0][0]))
```

I get this as output but not the data:

```
['ns1__images', 'ns1__definition']
```

I want to access the data in properties by using its key and get the value.
e.g. If I gave key as ns1_images, I want to get an output as the ns1_image URL.

Comment: use `type()`  to check type of data `print( type( new_var[0][0] ) )` - It can be dictionary and you can get all with `new_var[0][0].items()`. Did you try `new_var[0][0]['ns1__images']` ?

Comment: use `print( type('A') )` and you also see `< >` in `<class 'str'>` . If object has not method `__str__` to convert object to string (ie. when you use `print()`) the it can use standard method (to convert it to string) which uses format `<information-about-object>`. It has nothing to do with database.

Comment: @furas thanks for the type() suggestion. It gave me the output as: `<class 'neo4j.v1.types.graph.Node'>`. I'll check with the neomodel docs for this specific thing then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query result is composed of :

- a list of result (the first array)
- for each result, you have an array of returned item (check the meta)

In your case, you query returns a `Node`, so that's why you have `<Node ... >`
This object (ie. `neo4j.v1.types.graph.Node`) comes from the Neo4j python driver.
You can check the doc here : https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/types/graph.html#neo4j.types.graph.Node

What you can do is : `print(results[0][0]['ns1__images'])`

- `results[0]` : Get the first result of you query
- `[0]` : Get the first column of your result, here a `Node`
- `['ns1__images']` : to retrieve the property `ns1__images` of the node